# Proving that $\mathcal{S} = \{E\subset X: E \text{ is countable or } X\setminus E \text{ is countable}\}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Suppose $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of subsets of $X$ that consist of exactly one element: $$\mathcal{A} = \{\{x\}:x \in X\}.$$ Prove that the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ containing $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of all subsets $E$ of $X$ such that $E$ is countable or $E^c$ is countable.

To prove this, I first want to show that $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra where $$\mathcal{S} = \{E\subset X: E \text{ is countable or } X\setminus E \text{ is countable}\}.$$

My question: I've already shown that $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Now, I think I need to show that $\mathcal{A}$ is contained in $\mathcal{S}$. How can I show this (since both $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ are sets of sets)? So, how can $\mathcal{A}$ be contained in $\mathcal{S}$? Also, lastly, I think I need to show that $\mathcal{S}$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ that contain $\mathcal{A}$. Can someone show how this can be proven?

Comment: $\mathcal A$ is contained in $\mathcal S$ means $\mathcal A \subseteq \mathcal S$. You can proceed with the smallest $\sigma$-algebra part by showing that any $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal A$ must contain $\mathcal S$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen To show that $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{S}$, I have: Let $P\in\mathcal{A}$. Then $P=\{x\}$ for some $x\in X$. Since $P$ is finite, and hence countable, $P\in\mathcal{S}$. Is this all that was needed to show that $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right!

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson That works, but that's not the interesting part of the proof. What you need to show is that if $\mathcal A\subset\mathcal M$, and $\mathcal M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then $S\subset\mathcal M$.

Comment: @DonThousand Can you please elaborate on how this can be shown? Also, according to your argument, would we not need to show that $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson You do need to show that, but the statement I mentioned is the harder part of the proof.

Comment: @DonThousand Okay, thanks. Here's what I gathered from your comment. Let $\mathcal{S}$ be an arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$. Then to show that $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathcal{M}$, let $E\in\mathcal{S}$. Now, of course, I need to show that $E\in\mathcal{M}$. To achieve this, would it suffice to show that $E^c\in\mathcal{M}$ and $\cup_{k}E_k\in\mathcal{S}$? I issue is that I am not sure about what *exactly* I need to prove.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: Let $\mathscr{M}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{A}$, so that $\{x\}\in\mathscr{M}$ for each $x\in X$. Suppose that $E\in\mathscr{S}$. If $E$ is countable, then $E=\bigcup_{x\in E}\{x\}$, so $E$ is the union of countably many members of $\mathscr{M}$. Therefore … ? And then you have to deal the co-countable members of $\mathscr{S}$.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you have already proved that
$$\mathcal{S} = \{E\subseteq X: E \text{ is countable or } X\setminus E \text{ is countable}\}$$
is in fact a $\sigma$-algebra.

Now, we have $\mathcal{A} = \{\{x\}:x \in X\}$ and let us prove that the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$  is equal to $\mathcal{S}$.

Since for each $x \in X$ , $\{x\}$ is countable, we have that $ \mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$.

Since $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it follows that
$$ \sigma(\mathcal{A}) \subseteq \mathcal{S} \tag{1}$$
where $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$ (the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$).

Now let us prove that $ \mathcal{S} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A}) $.

We will begin by proving the **claim**:

> Every countable set $F\subseteq X$ is in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

**Proof of the claim**:
Since for every $x \in X$ , $\{x\} \in \mathcal{A} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and every countable set $F\subseteq X$ is a countable union of single-point sets, we have that $F \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ (because $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra). So, every countable subset of $X$ is in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ . $\square$

Now, for any $E \in \mathcal{S}$, we have two possibilities:

1. $E$ is countable. In this case, it follows directly from the claim that $E \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.
2. $X\setminus E$ is countable. In this case,  it follows directly from the claim that $X\setminus E \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$. Since  $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have $X\setminus(X\setminus E) \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$. But $X\setminus(X\setminus E) =E$, so we have $E \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

So, in both cases, we have that  $E \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.
So, we have:

$$ \mathcal{S}= \{E\subseteq X: E \text{ is countable or } X\setminus E \text{ is countable}\} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A})  \tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$ \sigma(\mathcal{A}) = \mathcal{S} $$
It means, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$  is equal to $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One question: how does $X\setminus E$ being countable imply that $X\setminus E \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$? (This is right above (2) in your answer.)

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson  Just before that sentence, we have proved that : "Now, since for every $x \in X$ , $\{x\} \in \mathcal{A} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and every countable set $E\subseteq X$ is a countable union of single-point sets, we have that $E \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ (because $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra). "

So, every countable set is in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson  I have updated the answer to include more details. Please, take a look and let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now, thanks so much!